# multiplicative property of complex exponentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

How can I demonstrate the property $e^u\cdot e^v$ = $e^{u+v}$ for complex $u,v$ using the summation definition of $\exp(z)$. Specifically this is the definition saying that $\exp(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}$. I feel like there should be an easy way to show this, but as of now I have both sums written  on a piece of paper and I can't find a way to proceed.

Comment: There is a way of doing this, using the series definition of the exponential. However the best route is to do that by way of calculus, rather than just looking at the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Cauchy product
$$\Big{(}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\Big{)}\Big{(}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}\Big{)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}$$
Where
$$c_{n}=\sum_{l=0}^{n}a_{l}b_{k-l}$$
Thus
$$\Big{(}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{n}}{n!}\Big{)}\Big{(}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{n}}{n!}\Big{)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{n}\frac{u^{l}}{l!}\frac{v^{n-l}}{(n-l)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{l=0}^{n}\frac{n!u^{l}v^{n-l}}{l!(n-l)!}$$
Using the binomial theorem
$$(u+v)^{n}=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\frac{n!u^{l}v^{n-l}}{l!(n-l)!}$$
We have
$$\Big{(}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{n}}{n!}\Big{)}\Big{(}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{n}}{n!}\Big{)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{n}\frac{u^{l}}{l!}\frac{v^{n-l}}{(n-l)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(u+v)^{n}}{n!}=e^{u+v}$$

Answer (score 0):

As I say in mycomment, you really don’t want to try to compare the series $\sum_{i\ge0}\frac{s^i}{i!}\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{t^j}{j!}$ and $\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(s+t)^k}{k!}$ directly, though with might and main, it’s possible that you could make your way to showing their equality.

I prefer to work formally for the most part, not worrying about considerations of convergence except at one point. Here’s what I mean:

Look at $E(x)=\sum_0^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}$. You notice that its formal derivative $E'(x)=\sum_0^\infty\frac{ix^{i-1}}{i!}$ is equal to $E$ again. Now, more generally, suppose you have a series $F(x)=c+\sum_1^\infty c_ix^i$ with the property that taking formal derivative (just sending $ax^m$ to $amx^{m-1}$ for each monomial) gives the result that $F'(x)=F(x)$. Working inductively, you see that $c_1=c$, $c_2=c_1/2$, $c_3=c_2/3$ and in general, $c_n=c_{n-1}/n$, in other words, $c_n=c/n!\,$. So the differential equation $F'=F$ forces $F(x)=F(0)E(x)$.

Now we’re ready to prove your desired equation $E(u+v)=E(u)E(v)$. Granting the truth of the chain rule in this situation, and thinking of $u$ as a constant (complex or real), the derivative of $E(u+x)$ is $E'(u+x)=E(u+x)$. Thus $F(x)=E(u+x)$ satisfies our differential equation, and so $F(x)=F(0)E(x)$. But $F(0)=E(u)$. In other words, $E(u+x)=E(u)E(x)$.

*“Granting the truth of the chain rule”*: you don’t need the full strength of this result, just the result that for series $g(x)$, the derivative of $g(a+x)$ is $g'(a+x)$. For this, it’s enough to show the fact for $g(x)=x^k$, a simple monomial. This means showing that the derivative of $(a+x)^k$ is $k(a+x)^{k-1}$. You can verify this directly using the Binomial expansion of $(a+x)^k$.