# Algebraically, can we declare such $H$ that $e^{-H}=0$ but $H+a\ne H$ (for scalar/real $a\ne0$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logarithms, infinity

I know that it is entirely possible to define on the extended real line $e^{-\infty}=0$. This will work well, because $a0=a e^{-\infty}=e^{\ln a -\infty}=e^{-\infty}$.

But can we introduce such thing as $H$ that has the property of $e^{-H}=e^{a-H}=0$, but at the same time $H+a\ne H\ne b H$?

Yes, of course, this would mean we would not be able to take logarithm of $e^{-H}=0$ (the logarithm would be multivalued) but other than this, does anything get broken?

In other words, given that exponential function of imaginary argument is periodic, why $e^{x-H}$ cannot be a constant (for such special element $H$ and scalar $a$)?

Comment: This seems like an exponential analogue of a wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we add in an a element $H$ to the complex numbers, and we want to have $e^{-H}=0$. We want to still have a integral domain so that $H+a\ne H\ne bH$ for $a\ne0,b\ne1$ and we won't lose multiplicative cancellation. And $H$ must be transcendental over the complex numbers as otherwise polynomials would have too many roots for it to stay an integral domain.

Then we can think about what properties of the exponential function we want to preserve, and see if it's possible. For example, if we want both $e^{x}$ to be always defined, and $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ to always hold, then we reach the contradiction $1=e^{0}=e^{-H}e^{H}=0e^{H}=0$.

It might be tempting to throw out $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$, but that follows algebraically from the infinite series definition, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2507263/26369) by [Kiryl Pesotski](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/417344/kiryl-pesotski). I'm not sure what $e^{x}$ is intended to be/do if we throw out $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$, so let's throw out $e^{x}$ always being defined.

As noted, if $a$ is complex, and $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ when everything is defined, then $e^{a-H}=e^{a}e^{-H}=0$. Also note that, for positive integers $n$, we have $e^{-nH}=\left(e^{-H}\right)^{n}=0$. And similarly, *if* $e^{-H/m}$ is defined for a positive integer $m$, then $\left(e^{-H/m}\right)^{m}=e^{-H}=0$ so that $e^{-H/m}=0$. So with maximal consistent definitions for the exponential function, we have $e^{-rH}=0$ for positive rationals $r$, but $e^{-0H}=e^{0}=1$. This means that the exponential function can't be continuous where defined, or that the function $x\mapsto-Hx$ is not continuous on the nonnegative reals (which has [serious consequences](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linear_Function_is_Continuous#Proof_1) - at minimum, I think the ring can't be normed anymore). Either of these would be really unfortunate. **Edit:** $\exp$ was analytic and single-valued on $\mathbb C$, so losing continuity here  is a loss even though I'm, in some sense, using the discontinuity of $0^x$.

If there are other properties you want to preserve, maybe they can be kept, but it seems that, at the very least, we are forced to lose a lot of nice properties.

Comment: This is good answer and yes, I can clarify what I had considered to drop. 1. Likely, $e^{H}$ is indeed not defined (division by zero). 2. Yes, $e^{-rH}=0$ for any positive $r$. This is expected. 3. Division is possibly not always defined, but it is unrelated to this question (although possible to drop, yes).

Comment: Yes, exponentiation is not continuous (but your example is just disguised $0^x$, which is not continuous anyway). But still, I do not see much other grave consequences... Am I missing something?

Comment: And, to be me precise, I envisaged $H$ as a divergent integral, more precisely either $H=\int_0^1\frac1xdx$ or $H=\int_0^1\frac1xdx-\gamma=\int_1^\infty \frac1xdx$.

Comment: @Anixx, dropping division opens up new possibilities. What properties of the ring would you want to preserve? For example, allowing zero-divisors would change some of the things I said.

Comment: No, no zero divisors, but I am OK with division not being defined sometimes (integral domain).

Comment: @Anixx I edited to weaken field to integral domain (which doesn't change much of what I said, I think), and to address your "$0^x$ is not continuous anyway" comment. Your comment about the integral is a whole separate discussion (that I think you already asked about in another MathSE question?) with its own issues and extends the scope of this question beyond what I am comfortable addressing in an edit.

Comment: So, for now the main problem seems to be non-existence of $e^H$. That's a problem I have to think about...